# Error when connecting to Siebel with Java Data Bean

Tags: java, siebel

I'm testing Java Data Bean following the code at Bookshelf: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B40099_02/books/OIRef/OIRefProgramming25.html#wp1004955

It fails at the line (I've modified with our Siebel server info):

```
m_dataBean.login("Siebel://SiebelServerhost:SCBPort/enterpriseServer/
      AppObjMgr_enu", CCONWAY, CCONWAY, "enu");
```

Stack:

> java.lang.ClassCastException: com.siebel.om.sisnapi.NAK cannot be cast
>   to com.siebel.om.sisnapi.HelloACK     at
>   com.siebel.om.conmgr.Connection.init(Connection.java:296)     at
>   com.siebel.om.conmgr.Connection.(Connection.java:140)   at
>   com.siebel.om.conmgr.ConnectionManager.open(ConnectionManager.java:134)
>     at com.siebel.om.om.CSSModel.login(CSSModel.java:1675)  at
>   com.siebel.data.SiebelDataBean.login(SiebelDataBean.java:217)     at
>   DataBeanDemo.(DataBeanDemo.java:28)     at
>   DataBeanDemo.main(DataBeanDemo.java:14)   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)     at
>   com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:147)

Comment: Are you reporting the error or do you have a question?

Comment: I'm just wondering what's going on, whether there's some config needs to be changed on Siebel server or something

Comment: Running across this as well.  Seems to be something on the Siebel side and not the application side as far as I can tell.  We're trying to integrate with the client's legacy system before they migrate away - they've been seeing this like crazy too, but their guys just reboot and it works.

Comment: Hi, I am facing same issue, were you able to resolve it ?